# crop - scale - center & fit an image into a round thumbnail

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I've been searching all over, but just cannot find a solution that could work in my case. 
I am trying to use CSS solution for this, I don't know how to implement jquery unfortunately, but maybe someone could point me to the right direction.

I have the following images as an example : http://pho.to/8rURy

That picture is quite self explanatory, I need to center, crop and fit the images into the thumbnail that is 80px x 80px

Currently I am stuck on the following CSS :

```
/* Image container */
.profile-img {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Image placed in the image container - there is a border around the image, but created as a background */
.profile-img img {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 5px !important;
background: #fff !important;
border: none !important;
border-radius: 999px !important;
}
```

The problem here is that the image fits into the container, however it is stretched ( shrunk to be exact ) to fit the container.

I need a solution that would crop, center and fit the image proportionally.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 2):

if u are using image size 80x80 then you have to use the class on that image as:

```
 .img-circle {

        border-radius:500px;
        -moz-border-radius:500px;
        -webkit-border-radius:500px;

        }


<img src="your image path" class="img-circle />"
```

Comment: hmm, okay, do I still keep the other settings for the image as in .profile-img img -border-radius: 999px; ??

Comment: just remove that and try border-radius:500px;

Comment: @Tester: is it useful for you

Comment: sorry for my late response, had to leave for a couple of hours. Thanks for your reply. But same here, the border-radius makes the image round, I know that, but it will shrink or stretch the image. I need the image to keep exactly the same ratio. Read my comment to Axel 's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the CSS attribute `border-radius` to make your profile images into a circle.

```css
.profile-img > img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 9999em;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}


/*Not necessary,  so you can see the white border */
body { background: #CCC; }
```

```html
<div class="profile-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know how to make the images round and if you look at the code in my question, i already have border radius there. The problem is that if the original image is for example 400px x 150 px, it will make it round, however it will shrink or stretch the image. I dont want that. What i need is basically the same as if you cover the head of that guy on the picture with a coin and cut around the coin.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image a background image and place it center/center. This way the image will be cropped and not scaled.

```css
.profile-img {
    width:         80px;
    height:        80px;
    border-radius: 999px;

    background-color:    #ccc;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Full images 1 and 2:</h3>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/150">

<h3>Center circle 1:</h3>
<div class="profile-img"
     style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/250/250')">
</div>

<h3>Center circle 2:</h3>
<div class="profile-img"
     style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/150')">
</div>
```

Center circle with PHP image URL:

```
<div class="profile-img"
    style="background-image: url('<?php
        echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0];
    ?>')">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. That actually sounds like a solution, but there is a problem with the img source. I wanted to use this code to generate the user avatar and this is a code how I am calling the avatar in my html markup - `<img src="<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>" />`

Can it still be used as you suggested ?

Comment: Just set the background-image: url('<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>'); in a style attribute in the profile-img div.

Comment: I have edited the example to use the style attribute to set image URL

Comment: Edited once more with PHP variable as background image URL. If my answer did help you, please mark it as accepted :)